# how to compare the result of a derivative with another algebraic expression?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, expression-test, function-comparison

I have come across this problem and wanted to automate it using MMA ,I have seen several examples from the forum, but none of them fit what I am trying to do.This is an implicit derivative which I can easily reach by hand, but there are alternatives and what I want is to compare my result with the alternatives, but I can't find the correct syntax

$y=5^{6 x^2-x+2}$
$y´=(12 x-1) 5^{6 x^2-x+2} \log (5)$
One of the following is assumed to be equivalent, as I can verify the equivalence

$a)\dfrac{2 x-2 y}{27 x^2}; b)-\dfrac{27 x^2}{2 y-2 x};c)\dfrac {2 y + x^2}{ 2 x y - 9 x^2 };d)\dfrac { 2 x y - 9 x^2 }{2 y - x^2};$

There it is in code format for your convenience
(although this code does not do anything )

```
y = 5^(6 x^2 - x + 2);
y` = 5^(2 - x + 6 x^2) (-1 + 12 x) Log[5];
a = (2 x - 2 y)/( 27 x^2);
b = (-27 x^2)/(2 y - 2 x );
c = (2 y + x^2)/( 2 x y - 9 (x^2) );
d = ( 2 x y - 9 (x^2) )/(2 y - x^2);
```

**edit
There was a sign error in alternative c is (+)
and number in function 2 instead of 5 , Fixed**

Comment: Re "One of the following is assumed to be equivalent": Equivalent to what?

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau_They ask for the implicit derivative of and , then the result obtained must be manipulated algebraically to arrive at some of the alternatives that appear there , here is the original problem https://postimg.cc/7G6JH99t

Comment: It does not appear to be correctly posed. For one thing, no implicit differentiation is required.

Answer (score 1):

How did you verify the equivalence? A numerical check suggests that this isn't so

```
y[x_] := 5^(6 x^2 - x + 5);
yp = D[y[x], x];
cases = Map[
   Simplify@ComplexExpand@{#, yp} &,
   {
     (2 x - 2 y)/(27 x^2),
     (-27 x^2)/(2 y - 2 x),
     (2 y + x^2)/(2 x y - 9 (x^2)),
     (2 x y - 9 (x^2))/(2 y - x^2)
     } /. y -> y[x]
   ];
cases /. x -> 5.

{{-2.076*10^102, 6.65314*10^106}, {-4.81696*10^-103, 6.65314*10^106}, {0.2, 6.65314*10^106}, {5., 6.65314*10^106}}
```

Comment: @ b3m2a1_ thank you for answering It must be an algebraic equivalence, because in my opinion they ask for one of those alternatives through algebraic manipulations

Comment: @BeTDa problem is...an algebraic equivalence should correspond to a numerical equivalence and I have yet to find a value for which the equivalence holds

Comment: b3m2a1_ correct a sign error, see above

Comment: @BeTDa still no numerical equivalence. Are you sure your problem is stated correctly?

Comment: b3m2a1_ there was another mistake , the problem link https://postimg.cc/7G6JH99t

Comment: @BeTDa The source could be wrong.  And probably is, imo. The derivative identity you seek, `Log[5] (12 x - 1) y == R[x, y]`, where `R` is a rational function with integer coefficients, seems improbable because `Log[5]` is a transcendental, not an algebraic number.

Comment: @Michael E2 I thought of something similar, because I didn't get to any of them by hand

Comment: b3m2a1_but anyway you taught me how to compare algebraic expressions which is what I didn't know how to do, your method is universal or has limitations?

Comment: @BeTDa Actually, my attention was focused on `Log[5]` but it's simpler than that. The exponential function is a transcendental function and does not satisfy a nontrivial equation of the form `Q[x,y] == 0`, where `Q[x,y]` is a polynomial with real coefficients. Just clear denominators in your case, and if the resulting polynomial is nonzero, then the answer is wrong. Well that's a theorem, but note that the solution `y[x]` should be a transcendental function by hypothesis, so it's not "universal" in the complete sense.